# The curvature tensor for different connections

Tags: differential-geometry

I have gotten stuck at an exercise that deals with the representation of curvature tensors for different connections.

[image]

These are the definitions I am working with.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I attempted to solve this by direct calculation.

$$
R^{\tilde{\nabla}}(X,Y) \psi
=\tilde{\nabla}_X \tilde{\nabla}_Y \psi 
-\tilde{\nabla}_Y \tilde{\nabla}_X \psi
-\tilde{\nabla}_{[X,Y]} \psi               \\
=(\nabla+A)_X (\nabla+A)_Y \psi            
-(\nabla+A)_Y (\nabla+A)_X \psi       
-(\nabla+A)_{[X,Y]} \psi                   \\
=\nabla_X \nabla_Y \psi 
-\nabla_Y \nabla_X \psi
-\nabla_{[X,Y]}\psi                       \\
+\nabla_X A_Y \psi-\nabla_Y A_X \psi
+A_X \nabla_Y \psi-A_Y \nabla_X \psi      \\
+A_X A_Y \psi-A_Y A_X \psi-A_{[X,Y]} \psi                                           
$$

Here the $A_X$ and $A_Y$ are sections into the space of endomorphisms on $TM$, i.e. $A_X, A_Y \in \Gamma(\text{End}(TM))$.

We have $R^{\nabla}=\nabla_X \nabla_Y \psi -\nabla_Y \nabla_X \psi-\nabla_{[X,Y]}\psi$. The next step should be to show

$$
d(A)=\nabla_X A_Y \psi-\nabla_Y A_X \psi
+A_X \nabla_Y \psi-A_Y \nabla_X \psi  \\
A \wedge A=A_X A_Y \psi-A_Y A_X \psi-A_{[X,Y]} \psi.                                            
$$

But this is where I am getting confused. If I interpret $d$ to mean the exterior derivative and $A$ as a 2-form then $d(A)$ is a 3-form that involves three directional derivatives which is inconsistent with my previous calculations. Similarly, if I attempt to compute $A \wedge A$ using the definition I get a sum over twelve permutations which are too many expressions. Where is my error?

Comment: Note that $A$ is an ($\operatorname{End}(E)$-valued) 1-form, rather than a 2-form.

Comment: In other words, fix a frame and write $A$ as a matrix.